# Dual R installation: 3.0.2 and 2.15.2 alongside

Tags: r, installation, multiple-versions

As some packages require newer versions of the R statistical framework and others are not updated anymore, there is now no way around having to install two versions of R on the university cluster.

The cluster is running Red Hat Linux and obviously we do not have super users privileges. My goal is to get  3.0.2 and 2.15.2 installed alongside in my home directory.

I have compiled both separately using different `.\configure PREFIX=` arguments to and that has worked well. But my bash profile still contains this line that will be read by both installations similarly:

```
export R_LIBS="/home/xapple/share/r_libs/"
```

This in turn leads to version clashes in the libraries:

```
< Failed with error:  'package 'MASS' was built before R 3.0.0: please re-install it'
```

Any elegant solution to having two libraries directories ? Thanks in advance !

Comment: why not have a pair of scripts that sets up the environment appropriately for the copy of R you're about to run?

Comment: Why not build the versions of older packages from source under R3.0X?